# How do I take a subset of a Vector by a Vector-of-indexes in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

*How do I create a new vector whose elements are the `idx`'s elements of `a2z`?*

```
val a2z = ('a' to 'z').toVector    // actually an arbitrary Vector of objects
                                   // 'a' to 'z' only for illustration
val idx = Vector( 3, 9, 22, 24 )
```

want

```
val res = Vector( 'd', 'j', 'w', 'y' )
```

I can use a simple for-loop, appending results, but would prefer to do it more idiomatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `map` over the indices:

```
idx.map(i => a2z(i))
```

and in the function passed to `map` get the element from the `Vector` by each index.

This should work with all collections (it's not limited to `Vector`).

---

As the argument `i` is only used once, this can be simplified to:

```
idx.map(a2z(_))
```

and as `Vector.apply` gets only one argument, this can be written like (as @Paul pointed out in a comment):

```
idx map a2z
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul for the hint, I have added both the long and your short version to the answer.

Comment: @Paul why/how does your code work?  I'm a bit confused about how data a2z becomes like a functor...  is it because operator() is special?

Comment: There are better explanations elsewhere, I'm sure, but in brief: Vectors are objects, () is syntactic sugar for .apply() (even for 'normal' functions, since functions too are Objects in scala). So a2z(i) is a function call to do the indexed access, and a2z is a function of one arg so can be applied to map.